# SWING component for simple image editing

Tags: java, swing, image-manipulation

Has anyone ever come by a SWING component which does simple image editing operations
such as crop, resize and zoom? I've found the following, which are either too complex or lack one of the functions i require (crop, resize and zoom)

1. http://www.jhlabs.com/ie/ (too complex).
2. http://www.eltima.com/products/visual-java-library/ (commercial license).

There is also http://asprise.com/product/jid/jimagedialog.php which seems to somehow be able to do what I'd like, but I'd love to know about any other components similar to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). It offers high quality resampling and it's easily [scriptable](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/index.html).